# How could I identify plain text website addresses and wrap them in an href tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field and when the page loads, I need to wrap any websites listed in that field with an href tag.

www.google.com needs to be changed to

```
<a href="www.google.com"><\a>
```

Not sure if this can be done with jquery or if I'd have to use regular expressions.

Comment: What is your definition of a *website*?

Comment: You need to provide a bit of code, like what you're getting and what your desired output would be, along with what you've tried up until this point.

Comment: We need more information to solve this problem?  So is this just an input box? Are you trying to just take an arbitrary string and turn it into a clickable link?

Comment: **Note that `<a href="www.google.com"><\a>` is NOT a valid hyperlink to the google website.** The protocol (http:// or https://) is missing, and the link will then be interpreted as a "page with that name" on YOUR OWN website. (Also, html tags should be closed using a slash: `</a>`, not a backslash)